# Redux not saving state in NextJS 13.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux, redux-toolkit, next.js13

I have a NextJS 13.4 website with app router, am using redux for state management. But all of a sudden my states won't save, my code:

src/app/page.jsx:

```
import styles from "@/styles/page.module.css";

import { store } from "@/redux/store";
import { fetchData } from "@/redux/dataSlice";

import Counter from "@/components/counter";
const Home = async () => {
  const req = await fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos");
  const data = await req.json();
  console.log(data); // this does return the array correctly
  store.dispatch(fetchData(data));

  return (
    <> Sample </>
  );
}
```

src/redux/dataSlice.js

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const dataSlice = createSlice({
  name: "data",
  initialState: {
    data: [],
    price: 0,
    tax: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    fetchData: (state, action) => {
        console.log(action.payload); // this again does return the array correctly
        state.data = action.payload;
    },
});

export const { fetchData } = dataSlice.actions;
export default dataSlice.reducer;
```

src/redux/provider.js

```
"use client";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./store";

function Providers({ children }) {
  return <Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>;
}

export default Providers;
```

src/redux/store.js

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import dataSlice from "./dataSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    data: dataSlice,
  },
});
```

src/app/layout.jsx

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import styles from "../styles/page.module.css";

import Providers from "@/redux/provider";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={styles.body}>
          <Providers>
            <div className={styles.content}>{children}</div>
          </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Note: it used to work earlier when i used client component with useDispatch hook, any help appreciated.